# HashTable with endless depth. Why? How to avoid?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When I use a $emptyHashTable variable to create an empty hashtable, it seems to generate an endless depth hashtable. Can't figure out why.
When I use @{} it works correct.

Code example

```
cls

$L1     = "L1"
$emptyHashTable = @{}

# Correct, hashtable contains 1 sub-hashtable
$proj1       = @{}
$proj1."$L1" = @{}

# Wrong, endless hashtable depth
$proj2       = @{}
$proj2."$L1" = $emptyHashTable

# Wrong, endless hashtable depth
$proj3       = $emptyHashTable
$proj3."$L1" = @{}

# Wrong, endless hashtable depth
$proj4       = $emptyHashTable
$proj4."$L1" = $emptyHashTable

Write-Host
Write-Host "proj1"
Write-Host "Level 0: " $proj1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 1: " $proj1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 2: " $proj1.L1.L1.GetType() # Will generate error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Write-Host
Write-Host "proj2"
Write-Host "Level 0: " $proj2.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 1: " $proj2.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 2: " $proj2.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 3: " $proj2.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 4: " $proj2.L1.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host
Write-Host "proj3"
Write-Host "Level 0: " $proj3.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 1: " $proj3.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 2: " $proj3.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 3: " $proj3.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 4: " $proj3.L1.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host
Write-Host "proj4"
Write-Host "Level 0: " $proj4.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 1: " $proj4.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 2: " $proj4.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 3: " $proj4.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
Write-Host "Level 4: " $proj4.L1.L1.L1.L1.GetType()
```

Outcome

```
proj1
Level 0:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 1:  System.Collections.Hashtable
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Xandorra\SQL\bmsHashTableTest.ps1:25 char:1
+ Write-Host "Level 2: " $proj1.L1.L1.GetType() # Will generate error: You cannot  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


proj2
Level 0:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 1:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 2:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 3:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 4:  System.Collections.Hashtable

proj3
Level 0:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 1:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 2:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 3:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 4:  System.Collections.Hashtable

proj4
Level 0:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 1:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 2:  System.Collections.Hashtable
Level 3:  System.Collections.Hashtable
```

I'm using Powershell 4.0
My $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value                                                               
----                           -----                                                               
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34014                                                     
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Powershell v4.
When the same code is run in Powershell v5, the endless depth does not occur.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the fact that objects are passed by reference, not by value.

It's the structure of your testing that's clouding these results. Run each individual `$projX` assignment in its own powershell instance without running the others, and it should work as expected.

For example, when you write:

```
$proj2."$L1" = $emptyHashTable

$proj3       = $emptyHashTable
$proj3."$L1" = @{}
```

you've set `$proj2.L1` to be a *reference* to `$emptyHashTable`. As such you also set `$proj3` to be a *reference* to `$proj2.L1` and hence to `$emptyHashTable`. That means that `$proj3.L1 = @{}` is the same as `$proj2.L1.L1 = @{}`, and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. When I set $proj2.L1 to be a reference to $emptyHashTable, you could say that $proj2.L1 is a pointer to $emptyHashTable. A pointer is one-way. So if I'm not mistaken, $emptyHashTable is not a reference back to $proj2.L1. When I then assign $emptyHashTable to $proj3, then $proj3 is a pointer to $emptyHashTable. I don't see how that can become a reference (pointer) to $proj2.L1.